# PDFs missing from iBooks on iPad after restore

Tags: ios, pdf, books

After a complete restore of my iPad 2 from iTunes, all my PDF books not from the iTunes Store were gone.  I just saw them for seconds and then disappeared.   How can I get them back?

Answer (score -2):

Look in the iTunes -> iTunes Music -> Books.   They should be there!